# IOS 7 masking issue - Not able save masked image from uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, masking

I have this piece of code working fine in IOS 6 but not saving masked image in IOS7, any explanation,suggestion ?

```
//Masking the image
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}


- (IBAction)savebtnclicked:(UIButton *)sender {


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage2.png"];
    UIImage *image = _imageFinal.image; // imageView is my image from camera
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

}
```

Comment: Does it through an error, does it save / do anything ?

Comment: You need to describe what it does wrong. Maybe show some screenshots.

Comment: it doesn't showing any error and any warning

Comment: @Simon McLoughlin it saves images but no modification in image simple copying on the other hand same code in IOS6 create two images with transparent image part

Comment: Check this thread [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939417/uiimage-masking-problems-ios-7 ]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both images (the image to be masked and the mask itself) have an alpha channel! 
This solved the issue for me on iOS7.